# Proving $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq\|x\|_2\leq\sqrt{n}\|x\|_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the inequality $\|x\|_{\infty}\leq\|x\|_2\leq\sqrt{n}\|x\|_{\infty}.$ I have made an attempt below, but I am unsure of my proof for the second inequality (during the third line where I introduce the inequality sign).

\begin{align}
\|x\|_{\infty}&=\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |x_j| \\
&=|x_p| \ \ \ \ \text{for some} \ 1\leq p\leq n \\
&=\left(|x_p|^2\right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq\left(|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+..+|x_n|^2\right)^{1/2} \\
&=\|x\|_2 \\
\therefore \|x\|_{\infty}&\leq\|x\|_2\\ \\
\|x\|_2&=\left(|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+..+|x_n|^2\right)^{1/2} \\
\|x\|_2^2&=|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2+..+|x_n|^2 \\
&\leq n\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |x_j|^2 \\
&=n\|x\|_{\infty}^2 \\
\therefore \|x\|_2&\leq\sqrt{n}\|x\|_{\infty}
\end{align}

Would it be better notation to write $\left(\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |x_j|\right)^2$, as opposed to $\max_{1\leq j\leq n} |x_j|^2$?

Comment: I believe it's true.

Comment: They are the same thing in this case but, by definition $||x||_{\infty}^2 :=(\max_{1\leq j\leq n}|x_j|)^2 =  \max_{1\leq j\leq n}|x_j|^2$

Comment: I like it better as it is.  Perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x \mapsto x^2$ is increasing  for $x\geq 0$ you have, for $x,y\geq 0$, that $x\leq y \implies x^2\leq y^2$.

Also, $\max(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)^2=|x_p|^2 $ for some $p$. Now since for every $j$ you have $|x_j|\leq |x_p|$ then for every $j$ you also have $|x_j|^2\leq |x_p|^2$, so that $\max(|x_1|^2,...,|x_n|^2)=|x_p|^2 $.

Thus $\max(|x_1|^2,...,|x_n|^2)=\max(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)^2$.

To conclude, since since for every $j$ you have $|x_j|\leq |x_p|$, then $|x_1|^2+...+|x_n|^2\leq |x_p|^2+ ...+|x_p|^2=n\max(|x_1|,...,|x_n|)^2$.

Your notation suggests two different interpretations for $\max$ which result yielding the same value, so it shouldn't be a problem.